# OPCClient memory leak in AddItems c++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, opc

I am tring to write OPCClient, but the problem is in memory leak.
This is my function to read values from OPCServer

```
VARIANT COPCClient::ReadValue(LPWSTR szItemID) {
    IOPCItemMgt* pItemMgt = NULL;
    tagOPCITEMDEF* pItems;
    tagOPCITEMRESULT* pResult = NULL;
    HRESULT* pErrors = NULL;
    tagOPCITEMSTATE* pItemValue = NULL;
    HRESULT hRes;
    DWORD updateRate = 1000;
    long bActive = 1;
    pItemMgt = NULL;
    //Добавление группы
    if (m_hGroup != 0) {
        hRes = m_pOPCServer->RemoveGroup(m_hGroup, 1);
        m_hGroup = 0;
    }
    hRes = m_pOPCServer->AddGroup((LPWSTR)(L"MyGroup"), bActive, updateRate,
        1, NULL, NULL, 0,
        &m_hGroup, &updateRate, (GUID*)&__uuidof(IOPCItemMgt), (IUnknown**)&pItemMgt);
   
    //Добавление элементов в группу
    DWORD dwCount = 1;
    pItems =
        (tagOPCITEMDEF*)CoTaskMemAlloc(dwCount * sizeof(tagOPCITEMDEF));
    pResult = NULL;
    pErrors = NULL;

    pItems[0].szItemID = szItemID;
    pItems[0].szAccessPath = NULL;
    pItems[0].bActive = TRUE;
    pItems[0].hClient = 0;
    pItems[0].vtRequestedDataType = VT_EMPTY;
    pItems[0].dwBlobSize = 0;
    pItems[0].pBlob = NULL;

    hRes = pItemMgt->AddItems(1, pItems, &pResult, &pErrors);


    IOPCSyncIO* pSyncIO = NULL;
    IID IID_IOPCSYNCIO = __uuidof(IOPCSyncIO);
    hRes = pItemMgt->QueryInterface(IID_IOPCSYNCIO, (void**)&pSyncIO);
    pItemValue = NULL;
    Sleep(50);
    hRes = pSyncIO->Read(OPC_DS_CACHE, 1, &pResult->hServer, &pItemValue, &pErrors);
    VARIANT res = pItemValue->vDataValue;
    pSyncIO->Release();
    CoTaskMemFree(pSyncIO);
    CoTaskMemFree(pItemValue);

    pItemMgt->Release();
    CoTaskMemFree(pItemMgt);
    CoTaskMemFree(pErrors);
    CoTaskMemFree(pResult->pBlob);
    CoTaskMemFree(pResult);
    CoTaskMemFree(pItems);


    return res;
}
```

I found on some sites(this indeed) that i need to free memory from hResult->pBlob, but it didn't help.
I'm sure that problem in AddItems. VS19 said that i lose 0.02 Kb in this function.

If you need more information about program or solution write what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be the full answer (it depends on the kind of data inside the value), but before doing CoTaskMemFree(pItemValue), you should also do VariantClear(pItemValue->vDataValue). That's a possible leak in the Read part, but it will only show itself with strings or other kinds of VARIANTs that have additional pointer in itself.

But, if you are looking for a leak related to AddItems: You are not freeing the pErrors that you get from AddItems. You are only freeing the pErrors you get from Read.